# Паралельное исполнение кода в yii

Tags: yii

Есть ли возможность паралельного асинхронного выполнения кода action в yii для нескольких пользователей? Спасибо

Comment: yii - это фрейморк на php. php запускается apache'ем, который может запустить много-много подключений и в паралель обрабатывать их, если только Вы сознательно не сделали припятствий для этого.

Comment: дело не в том.Просто есть action который парсит сайты,время его выполнения около 40 секунд.Но выходит так,что пока один пользователь не закончит ис под своего аккаунта этот процес,другой не может запустить ту же функцию.Более того,весь сайт для иных пользователей просто "зависает",на время выполнения.

Comment: К примеру, Ваш скрипт может лочить базу и будет наблюдаться подобное. Либо VPs очень дешевый и позволяет запустить один процесс апача.

Comment: vps.ua/Возможно в нем проблема?А что значит "лочить"?)

Comment: лочить - это блокировать, получать в монопольное владение какой то ресурс (в данном случае базу).

Comment: спасибо.Иду проверять

Comment: а самому естьвозможность на сервере запустить многопоточность в апач?

Comment: нужно поправить конфиг. Но для начала я бы просто проверил это с ssh консоли. что то вида `ps aux | grep apache` или `ps aux | grep http`